# Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. How to fix?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

While syncing current project i am getting warning like: "Error Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation and 'api'. how to fix this error.

build.gradle(PROJECT: xyz)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.0"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
     }

     task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
```

bulid.gradle(module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.wordpress"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'


    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'

}
```

[WARNING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka36A.jpg)

I have tried to change 'compile' to 'implementation'.

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app

Comment: You are bringing in Realm's gradle plugin at version 2.2.0 which adds Realm dependencies as `compile`. You might want to either upgrade Realm, or add the dependencies manually as it is indicated in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The warning probably caused by other libraries that you import to your application.
In their gradle, they imported other libs using the deprecated `compile` word.

**Update your libraries to the latest versions**
I recommend syncing gradle-files and building the project after each change to build.gradle in case something not working with your android libs or compiled sdk version etc.

Comment: @Vibhu when you says that 'I have tried to change 'compile' to 'implementation''; where did you do this change in app/build.gradle, as i see all of them are using 'implementation'

Answer (score 0):

Try updating

`com.google.gms:google-services from 4.0.1 to 4.2.0` (current latest version).

The latest version will be suggested automatically by the Android Studio.

Similarly, try upgrading the packages that you have included.